# Using notification center on mac, how to avoid Obj-C/Obj-C++ and QT

Tags: c++, macos

I have CLI application from which I want to send a notification to the notification center on MacOS. The application is programmed in C++14

One of the requirements for the application is C++ only! My problem is that I cannot find a method for sending a notification via a Core or Foundation without using Obj-C and Obj-C++. 
So can it be achieved in pure C++? and if yes, how?

Installing applications such as terminal-notify is not an options as it will run on clients computers, and I am not going to install applications behind their back

Answer (score 0):

You can use `system` to show your notification using AppleScript.

e.g.

```
system("osascript -e 'display notification \"message\" with title\"title\" subtitle \"subtitle\"'");
```

Comment: Can I somehow do so it does not show like it is the script editor that send the notification? - This could be a temp solution though fanks :D

Comment: I don't think so, no. I think the notification looks at the "bundle" of the app that sent it, and uses that to infer the icon / application name / etc. There may be a way to "trick" it but I don't know...

Comment: Damn it, then my project leader will probably will kill me, if I use it :/

Comment: I think your only other option will be to ship a bundle alongside your application that you can use to fire the notifications (at that point, you might as well use terminal-notifier). It doesn't need to be "installed" exactly, but depending on how you ship your app that may or may not be an option for you.

Comment: it will not be an option :(